# AttributeError: App instance has no attribute 'updateRed'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Could someone please advise why I am getting the following error. I am designing this GUI in raspberry pi. Does this problem related to a python version?

````
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui_sliderRGB.py", line 46, in <module>
    app = App(root)
  File "gui_sliderRGB.py", line 27, in __init__
    orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.updateRed
AttributeError: App instance has no attribute 'updateRed'
```
````

I am trying to call the function updateRed in Scale() in **init** method.

Here's the Code: -

````
```
from Tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)

pwmRed = GPIO.PWM(18, 500)
pwmRed.start(100)
pwmGreen = GPIO.PWM(23, 500)
pwmGreen.start(100)
pwmBlue = GPIO.PWM(24, 500)
pwmBlue.start(100)

class App:
     def __init__(self, master):
     frame = Frame(master)
     frame.pack()
     Label(frame, text='Red').grid(row=0, column=0)
     Label(frame, text='Green').grid(row=1, column=0)
     Label(frame, text='Blue').grid(row=2, column=0)
     scaleRed = Scale(frame, from_=0, to=100,
     orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.updateRed)
     scaleRed.grid(row=0, column=1)
     scaleGreen = Scale(frame, from_=0, to=100,
     orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.updateGreen)
     scaleGreen.grid(row=1, column=1)
     scaleBlue = Scale(frame, from_=0, to=100,
     orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.updateBlue)
     scaleBlue.grid(row=2, column=1)


def updateRed(self, duty):
     pwmRed.ChangeDutyCycle(float(duty))
def updateGreen(self, duty):
     pwmGreen.ChangeDutyCycle(float(duty))
def updateBlue(self, duty):
     pwmBlue.ChangeDutyCycle(float(duty))

root = Tk()
root.wm_title('RGB LED Control')
app = App(root)
root.geometry("200x150+0+0")
root.mainloop()
```
````

Comment: your function definitions seem to be outside of the class. Is that a copy-paste error?

Comment: yes, it is a copy-paste error.